# Use parent property setter when overriding in child class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a situation where I am overriding just the setter on a property:

```
class Parent:
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__dict__['x']
    @x.setter
    def x(self, val):
        self.__dict__['x'] = f'P{val}'

class Child(Parent):
    @Parent.x.setter
    def x(self, val):
         super().x = val
         print('all set')
```

Here, the print statement represents the processing I want to do after invoking the parent's setter. You can just ignore it. `super().x = y` is my native attempt at invoking said setter. It fails with

```
Attribute error: 'super' object has no attribute 'x'
```

What is the correct way to use the property setter from the parent class in the child?

I'd prefer to avoid the following, even though it works just fine, since it involves explicitly calling dunder methods:

```
Parent.x.__set__(self, val)
```

As a bonus, is there any way to use `super()` in the body of the child's setter?

Comment: One quick way out of this is to define a separate method which the setter actually calls, and then subclasses override that method.

Comment: You could also just manually call the setter out of the parent property, but that’s probably not as understandable as metatoaster’s solution, and won’t automatically handle multiple inheritance the way `super` does, etc.

Comment: Why not `super().__dict__['x'] = val`?

Comment: @khachik. The whole point is to avoid re-implementing the parent setter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the property's [fset](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) function:

```
class Child(Parent):
    @Parent.x.setter
    def x(self, val):
        Parent.x.fset(self, val)
        print('all set')
```

Answer (score 1):

I posted a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77728680/python-3-x-how-should-one-override-inherited-properties-from-parent-classes).

After a correction to a mistake of mine(by @ShadowRanger) the answer I preferred most was:

```
class Child(Parent):
    @Parent.x.setter
    def x(self, val):
         super(__class__, type(self)).x.fset(self, val)
         print('all set')
```

However, I absolutely agree that `super().x = val` would be a much more natural construct, but would need resolving by the python compiler.

Comment: This is basically the same as Martin's answer, with the replacement of `Parent` by `super()`. You likely don't need `__class__, type(self)` here at all.

Comment: You do need the `__classs__, type(self)` and using `super()` resolves the `type(self).__mro__` to the next ancestral definition (you don't need apriori knowledge where the property is defined).

Comment: Sorry, apologies I still have `@Parent.x.setter` as a decorator.  That's not going to work in the general case that the property `x` is somewhere up the `__mro__` chain.