# Python 3.x: How should one override inherited properties from parent classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, properties, super

A simple example probably shows more:

```
class NaturalNumber():
    def __init__(self, val):
        self._value = val

    def _get_value(self):
        return self._value

    def _set_value(self, val):
        if val < 0:
            raise ValueError(
                f"Cannot set value to {val}: Natural numbers are not negative."
            )
        self._value = val

    value = property(_get_value, _set_value, None, None)


class EvenNaturalNumber(NaturalNumber):
    # This seems superfluous but is required to define the property.
    def _get_value(self):
        return super()._get_value()

    def _set_value(self, val):
        if val % 2:
            raise ValueError(
                f"Cannot set value to {val}: Even numbers are divisible by 2."
            )
        super()._set_value(val)

    # This seems superfluous but parent property defined with parent setter.
    value = property(_get_value, _set_value, None, None)
```

This is a simplified example from a real usecase where I want to inject code for testing over production classes.  The principle is the same, and here I am introducing an extra validation to `value` in the `EvenNaturalNumber` class that inherits from the `NaturalNumber` class.  My boss doesn't like me getting rid of all his decorators, so ideally a solution should work however the underlying class is written.

What would seem natural is:

```
class NaturalNumber():
    def __init__(self, val):
        self._value = val
    
    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value
    
    @value.setter
    def value(self, val):
        if val < 0:
            raise ValueError(
                f"Cannot set value to {val}: Natural numbers are not negative."
            )
        self._value = val


class EvenNaturalNumber(NaturalNumber):
    @property
    def value(self):
        return super().value
    
    @value.setter
    def value(self, val):
        if val % 2:
            raise ValueError(
                f"Cannot set value to {val}: Even numbers are divisible by 2."
            )
        super().value = val
```

But this errors with valid sets on EvenNaturalNumber.value (say, = 2). With `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'value'`.

Personally, I would say that's a bug in the python language!  But I'm suspecting I have missed something.

---

I have found a solution using decorators but this seems rather convoluted:

```
class NaturalNumber():
    def __init__(self, val):
        self._value = val

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, val):
        if val < 0:
            raise ValueError(
                f"Cannot set value to {val}: Natural numbers are not negative."
            )
        self._value = val


class EvenNaturalNumber(NaturalNumber):
    @property
    def value(self):
        return super().value
    
    @value.setter
    def value(self, val):
        if val % 2:
            raise ValueError(
                f"Cannot set value to {val}: Even numbers are divisible by 2."
            )
        super(type(self), type(self)).value.fset(self, val)
```

And another way is:

```
class NaturalNumber():
    def __init__(self, val):
        self._value = val
    
    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value
    
    @value.setter
    def value(self, val):
        if val < 0:
            raise ValueError(
                f"Cannot set value to {val}: Natural numbers are not negative."
            )
        self._value = val


class EvenNaturalNumber(NaturalNumber):
    # This seems superfluous but is required to define the property.
    def _set_value(self, val):
        if val % 2:
            raise ValueError(
                f"Cannot set value to {val}: Even numbers are divisible by 2."
            )
        NaturalNumber.value.fset(self, val)

    # This seems superfluous as parent property defined with parent setter.
    value = NaturalNumber.value.setter(_set_value)
```

But this second solution seems rather unsatisfactory as it makes use of the knowledge that the value property is defined in the `NaturalNumber` class.  I don't see any way to iterate over the `EvenNaturalNumber.__mro__` unless I do this in `EvenNaturalNumber._set_value(self, val)`, but that's the job of `super()`, isn't it?

Any improvement or suggestions will be gratefully received.  Otherwise, my boss is just going to have to live with `super(type(self), type(self)).value.fset(self, val)`!

---

Added 01/01/2024.

Many thanks to ShadowRanger for pointing out the error with `super(type(self), type(self))`; I completely agree this should be `super(__class__, type(self))` (mia culpa).

Why this has arisen is as follows.  My parent classes would be better named `Device` (equivalent to `NaturalNumber` above).  These talk to external devices over a serial connection (using pyserial).  Various attributes on the external devices are exposed in the class as properties.  So a getter will write to the external device to query a value and return the reply as the value appropriately decoded and typed for the callee.  The setter writes to the device to set the value there and then checks there has been an appropriate reponse from the device (all with apropriate error handling for exceptional circumstances).  Needless to say, the whole system is about getting these devices to interact in interesting ways.  All of this seems quite natural.

I am building a test system over the top of this so that (to some extent) the entire system can be tested (unit / functional / regression etc.) without actually being connected to any of the devices: I hesitate to use the phrase "test harness" but perhaps justified in this case.  So the idea is to use inheritance over each `Device` class and have a `MockDevice` class that inherits from its parent and exposes the same properties.  But each `MockDevice` class is initialised with a `MockSerialConnection` (as opposed to a real `SerialConnection` which the `Device` classes are initialised with), so that we can inject the expected responses into the `MockSerialConnection`, which are then read by the `Device` code and (hopefully) interpreted correctly, thus providing a mechanism to test changes to the code as the system develops.  It is all smoke and mirrors, but hopefully in a good way.

For the `MockDevice` properties the getters and setters need to set the relevant serial communication and then call the relevant getters and setters of the parent `Device` class, so that we have good code coverage.  There is quite a lot of multiple inheritance going on here too (thank goodness for the `__mro__`), and exactly where in the inheritance hierachy a method or property is defined isn't completely fixed (and may vary in the future).  We start with `AbstractDevice` classes that essentially define functionality of the device (with a whole class heirachy here for similar devices with more or fewer features or functionality), the actual `Device` class represents a specific device (down to catalogue number) from a given manufacturer, which is not only dependant of the `AbstractDevice` but the communication protocol (and type of serial connection) together with specifics (such as the commands to send for a specific attribute).

The helper function solution while good for providing functionality that is easily overriden (library authors take note) doesn't quite fit the bill here for the purpose of testing.  There is nothing stopping another developer down the road applying a "quick fix" to the setters and getters (rather than the relevant helper functions), that would never be picked up by the test system.  I also don't really see the difference from my first code sample where I specifically define `_get_value` and `_set_value` and declare the property with `value = property(_get_value, _set_value, None, None)` and avoid the decorators.

I am also a little disatisfied with the `@NaturalNumber.value.setter` solution because it needs apriori knowledge that the property being set resides in the `NaturalNumber` class (the improvement over my earlier solution accepted).  Yes, I can work it out how it is now but as a test system it should work if down the line a developer moves the functionality to another place in the inheritance hierarchy.  The test system will still error but it means we will need to maintain code in two places (production and test); it seems preferable that the test system walks the **mro** to find the relevant class property to override.  If one could `@super().value.setter` then that would be perfect, but one can't.

Notice that there is no problem in the getters:

```
class EvenNaturalNumber(NaturalNumber):
    @property
    def value(self):
        return super().value
```

works just fine.  This is why I am tempted to think of this as a "language bug".  The fact that `super(__class__, type(self)).value.fset(self, val)` works suggests (to me) that the python compiler would be able to detect `super().value = val` as a setter and act accordingly.  I would be interested to know what others thought about this as a Python Enhancement Proposal (PEP), and if supportive what else should be addressed around the area of properties.  I hope that helps to give a fuller picture.

Also if there are other suggestions on a different way to approach the test harness, that will also be gratefully received.

Comment: Not providing and answer, just an explanation. Your first example works because it creates a new property object in the subclass, while the second example fails because it tries to modify the superclass’s property object, which isn’t accessible in the subclass. Otherwise @shadowranger reply is probably the way to go, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51879805/use-parent-property-setter-when-overriding-in-child-class

Comment: Thank you culicidae, I hadn't found that question on stackoverflow, it does seem to be the same, but the answer here from ShadowRanger seems more complete; namely `super(__class__, type(self)).value.fset(self, val)`.  That seems to be the way I'll go (at least, for now).

Comment: I think your actual problem is that "*For the `MockDevice` properties the getters and setters need to set the relevant serial communication and then call the relevant getters and setters of the parent `Device` class, so that we have good code coverage.*". **Either** you should mock the getters and setters to always return a `MockSerialConnection` (and not test the parent getters/setters "for coverage" - if they contain relevant code that needs to be tested, do that in a separate test) **or** just use the original getter/setter code to assign the `MockSerialConnection`, and get coverage on them

Comment: I think it is bad to use getters and setters to sync values with the device. There are several reasons for this but the biggest might be that getters and setters are not async and from my experience you will soon reach the point where you want to communicate with your devices in an async manner (using `asyncio` for example).

Comment: Hi DarkMath, yes where we imploy getters and setters the code is not async: because we want to block until we have the response.  Other devices are async but employ the same `Mock` class structure for the test system (essentially using a fifo queue as a back log of messages to be read).  It is probably not worth diving into specifics, and I would say that overriding a property (getters, setters) is as natural as overriding any other function (my opinion).  You mention there may be other reasons, I wil be grateful if you ellaborate.  Thank you for your continued considerations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first off:

`super(type(self), type(self))` is straight up *wrong*; *never* do that (it seems like it works when there is one layer, it fails with infinite recursion if you make a child class and try to invoke the setter on it).

Sadly, this is a case where there is no elegant solution. The closest you can get, in the general case, is the *safe* version of `super(type(self), type(self))`, using that code as-is, but replacing `super(type(self), type(self))` with `super(__class__, type(self))`. You can simplify the code a little by having the child class use a decorator rather than manually invoking `.setter`, getting the benefits of your `value = NaturalNumber.value.setter(_set_value)` solution more succinctly:

```
class EvenNaturalNumber(NaturalNumber):
    # No need to redefine the getter, since it works as is
    # Just use NaturalNumber's value for the decorator
    @NaturalNumber.value.setter
    def value(self, val):
        if val % 2:
            raise ValueError(
                f"Cannot set value to {val}: Even numbers are divisible by 2."
            )
        # Use __class__, not type(self) for first argument,
        # to avoid infinite recursion if this class is subclassed
        super(__class__, type(self)).value.fset(self, val)
```

`__class__` is what no-arg `super()` uses to get the definition-time class for the method (whenever `super` or `__class__` are referenced in a function being defined within a class, it's given a faked closure-score that provides `__class__` as the class the function was defined in). This avoids the infinite recursion problem (and is slightly more efficient as a side-benefit, since loading `__class__` from closure scope is cheaper than calling `type(self)` a second time).

That said, in this *particular* case, the best solution is probably to do as [DarkMath suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77734136/364696), and use an internal validation method that the setter can depend on, so the `property` need not be overridden in the child at all. It's not a general solution, since the changes aren't always so easily factored out, but it's the *best* solution for this particular case.

Comment: Hi ShadowRanger, thank you for your considered response.  Especially, for pointing out the problem with `super(type(self), type(self))`.  I absolutely agree now this should be `super(__class__, type(self))` for the purpose of inheritance from my child class (mia culpa).  I will give a fuller reply to get a little deeper into the issue and why it has arisen.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want to call a parent property in a overridden property. Can you please explain why you want to do that?

I mean, the *normal* my of doing this would be a helper method that can be overridden and called easily:

```py
class NaturalNumber:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self._value = val

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, val):
        self._validate(val)
        self._value = val

    def _validate(self, val: int | float) -> None:
        if val < 0:
            raise ValueError(
                f"Cannot set value to {val}: Natural numbers are not negative."
            )


class EvenNaturalNumber(NaturalNumber):
    def _validate(self, val: int | float) -> None:
        super()._validate(val)
        if val % 2:
            raise ValueError(
                f"Cannot set value to {val}: Even numbers are divisible by 2."
            )
```

Another possible way would be the avoid getter and settes completly and use frozen dataclasses instead with a `copy_with()` method. This also has the nice benefit that you get rid of possible side-effects due to the setters.
Here's the code example:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields
from typing import override, Self


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class NaturalNumber:
    value: int | float
    name: str  # just for demonstration purposes of copy_with()

    def copy_with(self, **kwargs) -> Self:
        """ Generic implementation that independent of concrete attributes. """
        current_values = {field.name: getattr(self, field.name) for field in fields(self)}
        return self.__class__(**(current_values | kwargs))

    def __post_init__(self) -> None:
        if self.value < 0:
            raise ValueError(
                f"Cannot set value to {self.value}: Natural numbers are not negative."
            )


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class EvenNaturalNumber(NaturalNumber):
    @override
    def __post_init__(self) -> None:
        super().__post_init__()

        if self.value % 2:
            raise ValueError(
                f"Cannot set value to {self.value}: Even numbers are divisible by 2."
            )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    number = EvenNaturalNumber(value=42, name='foo')
    number = number.copy_with(value=2)
```

Comment: In the dataclasses example, `copy_with` is reinventing a wheel; `dataclasses` already provides [`dataclasses.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.replace), so, if you *must* have a method to do it, the implementation would just be `return dataclasses.replace(self, **kwargs)`. It guarantees `__post_init__` is still called, so the validation will still work. You can just skip providing `copy_with` and leave it to your users to call `dataclasses.replace` themselves directly of course; `obj.copy_with(a=b)` is not improving on `dataclasses.replace(obj, a=b)`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know that `dataclass.replace` exists, what a shame.

Comment: Thank you DarkMath for your reply.  I have added to my original post a much fuller description of the use case (which is to create a test harness which makes the use of helper functions not quite so good).  I am not sure where you are going with the `@dataclass` example, but if you suggest this is a way froward for the test system I describe then I will look further into that.